# context path and subpaths

Tags: uri, 7

I have a problem with Context path condition. I would like on the conditions region to assign something like path/* where * indicates all its subpaths. For instance, if we have path/subpath1/subpath2 the context condition should match on path, subpath1 and subpath2.

Is it possible to do that on Context?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm *pretty* sure that just checking it against `path*` should work.

So rather than `path/*` or `path/*/*` just run it against `path*`.